# space left on header and footer in 4 inch retina iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

why some space left on header and footer portion of iPhone 4-inch simulator. its running fine on normal iPhone screen.i just developed app on Xcode 4.3 but after upgrading to 4.5 there one option to change simulator retina to 4 inch screen and its left some space automatically on header and footer which i focus by red box in below image.

[image]

Comment: Have you added the necessary 4" Retina start image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see that you have a warning about the *Default-568h@2x.png* file, the retina display splash. Add it and if the screen was designed properly it should fill the black gaps.

Comment: its not my splash screen its my first screen.how can i create dynamic view that can automatically fix in 3.5 and 4 inch view perfectly.

Comment: You've to add the 4 inch splash to support the new aspect ratio. Afterwards, test your app and if needed modify the autoresizing mask to your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your application doesn't support iPhone 5 (4" screen). You can enable support of this screen by adding to your project launch image 4" - Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136 px)

Comment: its not my splash screen its my first screen.how can i create dynamic view that can automatically fix in 3.5 and 4 inch view perfectly.

Comment: As atxe writes, you have to add 4" launch image to inform iOS that you want to support new resolution. When you add this image, system will resize your views.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using simulator 6.0 for running your Project.

It's for iphone 6 development.

so change your simulator to below version from 6.0 or

Just Rename your Default.png to Default-568h@2x.png

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: its not my splash screen its my first screen.how can i create dynamic view that can automatically fix in 3.5 and 4 inch view perfectly.